# Difference between wrap_content and match_parent while using in list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a list view with textview inflated by custom adapter. My question is what is the difference if I'm creating a listview with height and width `wrap_content` and with `match_parent`.

Here I'm adding my code.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content/match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content/match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public static final String[] titles = new String[]
    { "Facebook", "Twitter" };
    ListView listView;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++)
        {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(titles[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

**RowItem.java**

```
public class RowItem
{
    private String title;

    public RowItem(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return title;
    }
}
```

**CustomListViewAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            Log.i("ListView",holder.txtTitle.toString());
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here I've a line `Log.i("ListView",holder.txtTitle.toString());` which is displaying more logs than the listview items inflated using `wrap_content`, while displaying completely perfect using `match_parent`.

Here is the **LogCat**:

- LogCat for listview with **width** and **height** equals to `wrap_content`

  > 05-01 16:59:49.817: I/ListView(545): android.widget.TextView@43e45020 
  >   05-01 16:59:49.867: I/ListView(545): android.widget.TextView@43e46350 
  >   05-01 16:59:49.897: I/ListView(545): android.widget.TextView@43e47ce0
- LogCat for listview with **width** and **height** equals to `match_parent`

  > 05-01 16:58:49.037: I/ListView(501): android.widget.TextView@43e526c8 
  >   05-01 16:58:49.088: I/ListView(501): android.widget.TextView@43e52f08

Comment: how much rowItem you are able to see in ListView in both Contidion?

Comment: Generally we use "ListView" width as match_parent and height as wrap_content and "ListView" item width-height as match_parent...

Comment: @Haresh Even in that case the same thing happens.

Comment: @Crazy Obviously two. :) But the logcat is showing that inflating 3 row items.

Comment: ListView is virtualized. Putting layout_height="wrap_content" is a bad practice because you say that you want the ListView to be as big as its content. So if you have thousands of items, ListView will have to meausre them.